# Ninject and WCF - Correct method to initialize the Inversion of Control Container

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, inversion-of-control, ninject

What is the correct method to wire-up your types in Ninject with WCF. I have got the WCF extensions and Ninject itself added to the WCF project via NuGet. But I am stuck with what to do next. I seem to be running into some outdated examples that use a global.asax instead of ServiceHostFactory. Is the ServiceHostFactory method the best one?

Where are the best current examples of Ninject usage with WCF? I'm unsure how to use the objects the Ninject WCF extension offers to do the wiring up.

More info:
I tried walking through -   https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.wcf/tree/Maintenance_2.2/src/Examples/WcfTimeService

My project was unable to resolve NinjectWcfApplication in the Global.asax.cs
This is why I thought this was no longer compatible or current with the latest Ninject.

Comment: What error were you getting when it wasn't able to resolve the NinjectWcfApplication?

Comment: I'm getting the "Error activating IntPtr No matching bindings are available..." error as well.  How did you resolve this?

Comment: hambonius, sorry I can't remember what I did to solve that piece. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link you provided is from 2.2 which is outdated. Just switch ob that page to the master branch

Comment: Any thoughts on the error: Error activating IntPtr
No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable.

Comment: btw, thanks for pointing me in the right direction - think if I can track down the error above I'll be set.

Comment: I also noticed I now have an AppStart folder and a NinjectWebCommon.cs file in it. Was this added by NuGet? Should I Bind my interfaces there or somewhere else?

Comment: It depends, if you are IIS hosting yes, otherwise no

Answer (score 4):

If you are using service activations (no .svc file on disk) setup the ninject hosting factory in your web.config

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment>
      <serviceActivations>
        <add relativeAddress="MyService.svc" service="MyService" factory="Ninject.Extensions.Wcf.NinjectServiceHostFactory" />
      </serviceActivations>
</serviceHostingEnvironment>
```

If you are using a .svc file you can edit the markup and add `Factory="Ninject.Extensions.Wcf.NinjectServiceHostFactory"` to the `<%@ ServiceHost ... %>` declaration.

Then you need to modify your global.asax to inherit from the NinjectWcfApplication and create the Kernel

```
public class Global : NinjectWcfApplication
{
    protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        return kernel;
    }
}
```

Comment: Any thoughts on my questions to Remo?

Comment: The AppStart folder is in fact added by Nuget (via the Ninjet package).  I would recommend creating your own class that inherits from NinjectModule and setup your bindings in the Load method.  That way you can load the bindings anywhere using Kernel.Load<T>

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used Ninject but typically I begin the wire up process in the ServiceHost implementation.  Something like:

```
public sealed class MyServiceHost : ServiceHost
{
    public MyServiceHost() : base() 
    {
        MyServiceLocator.SetAsDefaultServiceLocator();
    }
}
```